# SpringData JPA dynamic projections retrieve all columns from MySQL

Tags: jpa, dynamic, spring-data, projection

I have an entity representing a MySQL table:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Getter
@Setter
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AccountEntity implements AccountBaseEntity, AccountRoleEntity, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private UUID accountId;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @NotBlank
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "role")
    @NotBlank
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "creation_time")
    @NotNull
    private Timestamp creationTime;

}
```

It implements this interface:

```java
public interface AccountBaseEntity {

    UUID getAccountId();

}
```

And then I have some projections also implementing it. For instance:

```java
public interface AccountRoleEntity extends AccountBaseEntity {

    String getRole();

}
```

This is my repository, which has a dynamic projection:

```java
public interface AccountsRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountEntity, UUID> {

    <T extends AccountBaseEntity> T findByEmail(String email, Class<T> type);

}
```

And I use it with this code:

```java
AccountRoleEntity accountRoleEntity = accountsRepository.findByEmail(email, AccountRoleEntity.class);
```

I inspect the query setting the Spring-Boot property `spring.jpa.show-sql = true` and this is what I see:

```sql
Hibernate: select accountent0_.account_id as account_1_0_, accountent0_.creation_time as creation2_0_, accountent0_.email as email3_0_, accountent0_.role as role10_0_ from account accountent0_ where accountent0_.email=?
```

I was expecting the query to select only the account_id and role columns, but it seems like it is retrieving the entity and converting it to the projection, instead of retrieving the projection itself. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is working as expected.

Comment: what do you mean? If I use static projections, it only retrieves the columns matching the interface getters (the problem with them is that I need to write a method in the repository per projection). Why is it different with dynamic projections? And, if it is working as expected, what is the purpose of dynamic projections? I'd rather use the full entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized this is because `AccountEntity` extends `AccountRoleEntity`. Is this the normal behaviour?

I want the entity to extend the projection so that I can have a common interface to be used in some methods that should work both with the entity and the projection.

EDIT:

As stated here (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2179), this is the expected behaviour. This is solved creating a super interface implemented by both the entity and the projection.